# Mac transforms my folder to an app

Tags: macos, filesystem

I have a GitHub repository where the folder structure is like this:

- MyCompany

  - Data
  - Web.Service
  - Web.Site
  - Windows.Application
  - ...

The problem is, when I pull the branch, there is the folder `Web.Service`. Mac renames the folder to `Web.Service.app` and thinks it's an app.

Now, my IDE can't work anymore with it. And I can't rename the namespace.

What can I do? Any suggestions?

Comment: The \*.service bundle shouldn't have been renamed to *service.app (check this, please), but it's treated as a special folder - similar as \*.app! [Treat folders with an extension like .service as regular folders instead of bundles in Finder](https://superuser.com/questions/350025/treat-folders-with-an-extension-like-service-as-regular-folders-instead-of-bund). **... you'd probably break stuff by removing this definition!**

Comment: @klanomath it's renamed to *.service.app - it now works..somehow..but I'm not really happy. So you say, I should not change this. So I guess I won't change it and try to talk to the c#-developers to change this, because Mac-users 

Comment: Is there a reason you can't change the name of the folder when you pull the branch? Call it "Web_Service" or "WebService" Just get the period out of the name.

Comment: @SteveChambers these are namespace-names in C#. It's kind of a "coding guideline" that folders are equal to those.

Comment: And here I go exposing my ignorance of a programmers life... oh well: never mind!

Comment: @SteveChambers haha well, that's okay :D

Comment: @MatthiasBurger **... you'd probably break stuff by removing this definition!** is just a warning in the answer, I wished to highlight!